# Now that I have a modem in bridge mode, how does it join the network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bridge-router

The router is an Arris SBG7600AC2. I was able to get it into bridge mode. That part was quite easy.

Now, I want to get the bridged router onto the network. How do I do that?

Once the bridged router is on the network, I will use a wired to connection to get the computer online. I assume the bridge point is connected and using a wired connect to the bridge will be somewhat stronger than the wireless use of the bridge.

Is there anything else besides, the joining of the network that I need to do? I read a similar question and it talked about DHCP being turned off and changing the IP. I have gone into my LAN settings and turned of the DHCP server and tried to make the IP within the "home router's" DHCP server range. This just restarts the router, and it says unit is updating. At this point I am walking away to let the update take even more time. Should it take this long?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why did you put the router in bridged mode?  Your third paragraph implies what you are doing and trying to do are quite different - for a start, you would not use bridged mode on your home routers DHCP range.  If you are just trying to bypass the WIFI, you don't need (and probably don't want) bridged mode.

Comment: Bridged mode means that the router is just converting the incoming cable signal to a WIFI signal - you still need something to act as a router (unless you only want to run a single computer and are OK with exposing that computer directly to the internet, which is a bad idea from a security POV if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: My network is weak. While wired I do a speed test and I get all 50, (which is the max you can buy from the local co. I am very rural).  If I unplug the device from the router, the speed goes down by about half.  I want to help the network. I use internet TV and have had the TV say its speed is <3MB and it won't play the show. I am moving the router from the office into the living room. That will resolve the TV issue. I am then going to be sending wifi back to the office. I want to build a bridge so the one device in the office, can do better than the very weak signal with zero support......

Comment: All you needy to do is connect the Arris SBG7600AC2 to your router. All you did with enabling bridge mode is disable the router in the Arris SBG7600AC2. Now you should connect the Arris SBG7600AC2’s ethernet port to the WAN port on your router. That’s it!

Comment: @NeedModemHelp Just read your comment here and this is starting to sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319). You seem to have Wi-Fi reception issues of some kind and believe setting your main ISP modem to bridge mode will help. If you ask me that might not help. It might be a case where the Arris ISP device is doing double-NATting if it is connect to another router. So perhaps that is the core issue here? That you have two devices doing DHCP and clogging up the network? In general, my previous comment still stands. Just connect the modem to the router WAN port.

Comment: zero support....ergo building a bridge. I am paying to move the router and want to avoid buying equipment I may not need. Already have router from old apt. Tempted to get extenders, been told about mesh networks but I don't the diff and which sys or specifics to buy.

Comment: Giacomo, I appreciate the counsel. I connected the router that is doing the internet & connected the arris to it. As to your XY problem post, the arris is not the ISP. Everything after that doesn't make sense to me. Sorry

Comment: Might I suggest asking another question outlining your problem and the resources you have at your disposal, and we may be able to help.  If you can provide some kind of network diagram that would be useful. Your problem is related to WIFI and using bridged mode likely won't help you.

Comment: You may be able to solve your problem by converting the router back into regular routing mode, then setting up your old router to act as an AP client if its capable of that, and then connecting that old router to your office with an ethernet cable.  Of-course, this assumes your old router is capable, and can pick up the signal strongly enough.

Comment: So you say this in the comments, “zero support....ergo building a bridge. I am paying to move the router and want to avoid buying equipment I may not need. Already have router from old apt.” So basically you want to use old Arris modem/router from old location in a new location? As I the new location already has an Arris modem/router and you think you can add a second router by just using the old Arris modem/router from the old location in the new one? And you somehow believe bridge mode has to do with this? Bridge mode is not your solution. You need to better explain your goals here.

Answer (score 1):

*Expanding, after comments.*
This, as John says, is a DOCSIS modem/router. It's unusual for these to have an ethernet WAN port. It's designed to take incoming 'cable' [mine runs on coax] & convert it to 'outgoing' ethernet RJ45 for further distribution. Unless it actually has an RJ45 WAN connection, your journey ends here & you need a wifi access point instead.

I found a picture of one online. Looks remarkably similar to mine… and has a cable line in with ethernet out. You cannot press it into service as an ethernet bridge/router.
It *may* function as a simple ethernet switch, in which case you could plug one socket to your existing router & two others to your TV and office computer.
Usually, once you reduce these devices to 'dumb modem' mode, the built-in wifi is disabled - as there's nothing running internally that can control it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Arris SBG7600AC2 is a DOCSIS cable modem. (I had one before my Hitron modem).

You put it in bridge mode, so now you need to get a Router and attach the WAN port of the router to the Arris modem.

I have my Hitron set for bridged mode.

Set up the WAN port (NOT LAN) and you should see the External IP your ISP has set for your system. The WAN setting would use DHCP to find the external IP.  That is likely all it needs. If you need a Subnet Mask use 255.255.255.255 (One IP).

Log into Router setup page to manage WAN settings (and later LAN settings). A router with factory settings is usually located at 192.168.1.1 or 102.168.0.1 .

This is how Bridged Mode works. The modem passes the Internet signal to the Router and the WAN section of the Router is your external setup.

I use a Cisco RV series Router, just check it and it has been set up as I describe above.

Comment: I am glad to get your help but 99% of that goes over my head. I have a router that is connected to the internet. The arris, the second router in the house, is in bridge mode.   After you say set up the WAN not LAN I am lost. sorry

Comment: The ports are marked directly on the router (any I have seen). You need to log into the router setup page to manage the WAN settings.

Comment: @NeedModemHelp I think a big part of the problem here is from your handle of “NeedModemHelp” to your odd response to attempts to help you, the issue at hand might not actually be a modem related issue. It might be best to start from square one: What is your goal here and what equipment do you have? It seems to me you have two Arris modems and somehow you want both of them to co-exist on the same network? Again, I believe you should not follow my, or anyone else’s, assumptions but edit your original question to outline _exactly_ what your goal is and specifics as to equipment and such.

Comment: Hey Y'all. sorry about ghosting my internet went down for a bit. I didn't explain myself clearly here and the question is now closed. I will try better next time.

Comment: @NeedModemHelp You can still edit your question to clarify it. And then, if you did make it clearer, your can vote to reopen the question. This community is here to help you. But in this case you need to clearly state what’s up.